# Creating a database file using db_load

Tags: python, linux, database, shell, command-line

Can anyone help me create a database using db_load. I have read through their man page like more than a couple times. But i still cant understand how to work with it.
Suppose i have input.txt file like

```
hey #first line 
you are # second line 
2 # first line 
same # second line
love # first line
3000 # second line
```

i want to use db_load to create a hash database with the first line being the key and the second line being the data

i have tried the following in linux shell command

```
db_load -T -t hash output.db
```

i dont know how am suppose to reference the .txt file in this command

please help??

Comment: What database is `db_load` associated with?

Comment: it is associated with Berkeley DB. and i want to use it to create a .db file

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a bit late, but yes- you need to specify an input file.
Create a text file, 'input.txt', and load its contents into a hash database, like so:

```
touch input.txt
echo user1 > input.txt
echo pass1 >> input.txt 
db_load -T -t hash -f input.txt output.db
```

This will create a file 'output.db' even if it doesn't already exist, with the content of 'input.txt'.

**Very important**, since it's been the cause of years of confusion to newcomers: In your application where you reference the 'output.db' file, specify it as 'output', without the '.db' extension. The application will automagically add the '.db' when looking for the file.

db_load man-page:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17275_01/html/api_reference/C/db_load.html
Real-world example (scroll down to the relevant section):
https://developpaper.com/explain-the-process-of-installing-and-configuring-the-ftp-server-software-vsftp-in-centos/